# Automatic timestamp when a cell is modified, but that clears when the cell is empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I have this code and i am trying to add some code at the bottom saying that if the column is empty, the date column will clear.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  //1.Change 'Ark 1' to be matching your sheet name
  
  if (r.getColumn() == 4 && ss.getName()=='Ark 1') { // 2. If Edit is done in  column 4 (D)  And sheet name is Ark 1 then:
    var celladdress ='L'+ r.getRowIndex() 
    ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");}
 
};
```

L is the column i have my date timestamp in, while column 4 (D) is the column the modification is done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain in your question either you mean the whole column being empty, or the active cell.

In any case:

- To verify that the cell is not empty or contains only a space you have to query for `if(r.getValue() !="" && r.getValue() !=" ")`
- Depending on the outcome - either you set a timestmap in the active row of column L or you clear the content of the respective cell in column L with `ss.getRange(celladdress).clear();`

Below is a sample:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  //1.Change 'Ark 1' to be matching your sheet name  
  if (r.getColumn() == 4 && ss.getName()=='Ark 1') { // 2. If Edit is done in  column 4 (D)  And sheet name is Ark 1 then:
    var celladdress ='L'+ r.getRowIndex();
    if(r.getValue() !="" && r.getValue() !=" "){
      ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
    } else{
      ss.getRange(celladdress).clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want the timestamp in column L to clear when i clear the text on column 4 (D), in the same row.

Comment: I don't think that solution works, because the original code is set to give a timestamp each time the column is modified. I think that overrides the ```if(r.getValue() !="" || r.getValue() !=" ")``` code. The timestamp updates when i clear the input in column 4, as it counts modification over ```else{
    ss.getRange(celladdress).clear();
  }```

Comment: Sorry, it should be `&&` and not `||` - updated now!